# Get input and pass variable from an if statement with Haskell

Tags: variables, haskell, if-statement, io

Here is a simplified version of the code I'm working on.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
     args <- getArgs
     if null args
       then putStr "> " ; userInput <- getLine
       else userInput <- readFile $ head args

     let conclusion = userInput
```

This won't work without do notation, the variable won't pass to *conclusion* below when I do use it, and the putStr, which I'm trying to use to create a kind of prompt, just makes it mad.

Is there something that I'm forgetting to add somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few problems here. First, you need to include `do` after `then` and `else`:

```
if null args
  then do putStr "> " ; userInput <- getLine
  else do userInput <- readFile $ head args
```

`if` in do notation is the same as `if` everywhere else; you have to put an *expression* after `then` and `else`, not statements, and you need `do` to turn a bunch of statements into an expression. This still isn't quite valid, though; the last statement in a `do` block must be an expression, but you have a bind here. After all, every statement has to have a result value, but a bind has none.

The second problem is, as you've observed, that this introduces a new scope, and so you can't access variables you bind from outside. This makes sense if you think about it; after all, you could bind the variable on one side and not the other. The solution is to simply move the bind *outside* the `if`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
     args <- getArgs
     userInput <- if null args
       then do putStr "> " ; getLine
       else readFile $ head args

     let conclusion = userInput
```

So, the action whose result we bind to `userInput` is still computed depending on the result of `null args`, but we bind the variable outside the conditional.

Note that I didn't add a `do` to the `else` branch this time; it's not required, since there's only a single expression there. (It's still valid, but it's unidiomatic to use `do` when it's not necessary.)

This code still won't work unless you put something after the `let conclusion = userInput` line (since, like I said, `do` blocks must end with an expression), but presumably you already have code there.

As an additional note, you should avoid using functions like `head` and `tail`; `head` is a *partial function* (not defined for every argument — `head []` will produce an error), and those are generally considered unidiomatic. You should use pattern-matching instead, like this:

```
userInput <- case args of
  [] -> do putStr "> " ; getLine
  fileName:_ -> readFile fileName
```

This is just like the pattern-matching used when defining a function, but for a single value rather than any number of arguments.

Comment: Rather than the weird `do`, I think it would make more sense to just use the monad operators directly: `if null args then putStr "> " >> getLine`

Comment: I think just learned more from your post about Haskell program structure than half of the Haskell tutorials I've looked through. Seriously. You've given me some good vocabulary to research. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Any variable bindings you do in the `then` and `else` blocks won't be visible in the outer scope, so you need to bind the result from the `if` clause itself.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    userInput <- if null args
        then do
            putStr "> "
            getLine
        else readFile $ head args
```

Comment: I need to do some more research on binding. I had no idea you could bind an if statement to a variable. That's clever. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @SubtleArray: syntactically, the right hand side of a binding statement can be **any expression**; `if ... then ... else` is just another type of expression, as is `case`.  You do also have to respect the type system, which requires that in a statement like `pattern <- expression`, `expression` must have type `Monad m => m a` (in your example, `IO a`), and `pattern` must have type `a`.  You can think of `if ... then ... else` as if it was a function of type `Bool -> a -> a -> a`, so that the type of the whole `if` expression is the same as the type of the `then` and `else` clauses.

Comment: +1 to both answers. As I also had no idea you could bind if statements in that way. Both pointed me in the right direction to solving an issue I had. Came sooo close to asking a question on SO, but once again I've found/figured out the answer thanks to existing questions.