# Using getArgs or user input

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments

New to Haskell and wrestling with a problem. I know *why* my code doesn't work, but I cannot figure out the solution.

The intention is for the user to provide a file name either via argument or, if none provided, prompt the user to enter the data. A message with the file name is printed to the screen and the file is processed.

```
import System.Environment
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let file = if null args
        then do putStr "File: " ; getLine
        else head args
    putStr "processing"
    putStrLn file
    writeFile file "some very nice text"
```

The code is wrong, of course, but demonstrates the logic I've been wrestling with. Neither *Happy Learn Haskell* nor *Learn you Haskell* could put me over the hump. The closest thread I could find was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216940/get-input-and-pass-variable-from-an-if-statement-with-haskell/9217189#9217189). Many thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us analyze the type of `file`:

```
let file = if null args
    then do putStr "File: " ; getLine
    else head args
```

Here the  `if`-`then`-`else` statement has as condition `null args`, which is indeed a `Bool`, so we are safe. But the the `then` part has as type `IO String`. So Haskell reasons that `args` should be an `[IO String]`, but it is not: it is a list of `String`s, so `[String]`.

Later another problem pops up: you use `file` as a `String`, but it is not: it is still an `IO String`.

There are a few ways to fix it. Probably the minimal change is to use `pure` to wrap the `head args` back into an `IO`, and use replace the `let` clause with a `<-` statement:

```
import System.Environment

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    file <- if null args
        then do putStr "File: " ; getLine
        else pure (head args)
    putStr "processing "
    putStrLn file
    writeFile file "some very nice text"
```

Comment: Dank u wel! Is there a reference for this? (Searching for "haskell pure" is impractical at best)

Comment: @Bill: well the [`pure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:pure) function is a bit cryptic. An `IO` is a `Applicative` type, and so you can wrap elements in an `IO` object with `pure` (but you can use `pure` to wrap elements in a `Maybe`, `[]`, etc. as well).

Comment: For example for the `Maybe` type, if you use `pure 14 :: Maybe Int`, you get a `Just 14`. For a list you get a singleton list (`pure 25 :: [Int]` is `[25]`). And for an `IO` you basically get a "no-operation" that has as output the parameter of the `pure` function.

Comment: I will research this further (I spent way too many hours trying to figure out a work-around). Thanks again.

Comment: @BIll If you need to again in the future, a good way to search for Haskell functions is through [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/). You can search by type or name.

Comment: @Bill If you'd like to make progress without being required to do a lot of research, I recommend [The IO Monad for People who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html). If you'd like to do a lot of research and acquire a deep understanding before you proceed, I recommend [You Could Have Invented Monads! (And Maybe You Already Have.)](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html).

Comment: @AJFarmar, @DanielWagner -- excellent suggestions, but `pure` was the missing link I needed. Trying to solve the problem without `pure` is a bit much for new-to-Haskell types (though I learned a lot creating dozens of ways it doesn't work!).

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `pure` over `return` in this context? I guess it's less confusing for people coming from languages where `return` means something else. But from what I've seen, `return` is historically more often used here, specifically in tutorials/books/etc, so I figure that's what people are more likely to recognize. I guess `pure` is better in general, since it's more ... well, general, but that's not as much of a factor if you know you're in IO from the get-go.

Comment: @DarthFennec: well there is probably already a batch of thousand of questions with people that find `return` confusing: most of the time they see it as a "keyword", not a function, and keyword that "returns" content from the top level of a function and terminates execution. I think naming the function `return` was probably a mistake. Not that much because `return` does not per se describes what it does, but more because nearly all imperative languages attached the same meaning to it. To avoid the confusion a lot of people here advice against `return`, and use `pure` instead.